# Issues with connection to mongo via ssh. Got message: MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 5000 ms

Tags: mongodb, ssh

I am trying to connect to MongoDB via SSH, but something seems to be wrong. I am getting the following error message: "MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 5000 ms".

[image]

At the same time I successfully connect to MongoDB through TablePlus.

[image]

I use the same connection string:

mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017

I've also tried modifying the connection string by adding the database name or using direct connection param:

mongodb://username:password@mongodb/database?directConnection=true

However, I am still unable to connect, even when using Compass.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this problem?

Also I am able to connect to SQL and Redis databases through SSH without any problems, so it seems like the issue is not with SSH.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551